# Aligning two-level optimization problem

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, align

I am trying nicely (and correctly) align two level optimization problem. At the moment came up with the following solution:

```
$
\begin{array}{llr}
    \min \limits_{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}} & -2x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 6y_1 + y_2^2 \\
    \st & x_1^3 + 3x_2 - 10 \le 0 \\
        & \displaystyle \mathbf{y} \in \argmin_{\mathbf{y}\in [0, 10]^2} \; 2x_1^2 + 2y_1^2 - 8y_2 \\
            & \hspace{1.25cm} \st - x_1 + 2x_1 - x_2^2 + 2y_1 - y_2 - 3 \le 0\\
            & \hspace{1.9cm}     - x_1 + 2x_1 - x_2^2 + 2y_1 - y_2 - 3 \le 0 \\
      & \mathbf{x} \in [-10, 10]^2,\; \mathbf{y} \in [-10, 10]^2
\end{array}
$
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Here I highlighted couple issues:

1. What would be a better way (compared to manual `hspace{}` the first constraint starting with keywords "s.t." align based on the upper line *min* keyword (see blue line in the picture). The rest constraints should be left-aligned by the first constraint.
2. Why am I getting different spacing for the inner constraints? Both are completely the same, but in the first constraint there is a bigger space after the minus sign (situation highlighted in picture in red "circle")

Comment: Try `{} - x_1` on the second line enclosed in the red circle.  The `{}` should create a (empty) group, which changes the minus-sign from an unary negative sign to an binary operator as in a - b.

Comment: 1. I'd say that it's better to treat `argmin` as one word and align **s.t.** to `arg' (as you can see, the `y\in[0,10]^2` is placed under `argmin`, not under `min`. What you want appears inconsistent. 2. The first `-` is incorrectly recognized as a binary operator. Just surround it with braces `{-}x_1...` to get the correct unary operator spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `array` environment, I'd suggest to try `aligned` (which is basically an `array` but with spacing more suitable for math). The MWE could be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\st}{s.t.}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
    &\min \limits_{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}} && {-}2x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 6y_1 + y_2^2 \\
    &\st && x_1^3 + 3x_2 - 10 \le 0 \\
        &&&\mathbf{y} \in
     \begin{aligned}[t]
        &\argmin_{\mathbf{y}\in [0, 10]^2} && 2x_1^2 + 2y_1^2 - 8y_2 \\
            &\st &&{-}x_1 + 2x_1 - x_2^2 + 2y_1 - y_2 - 3 \le 0\\
            &&&{-}x_1 + 2x_1 - x_2^2 + 2y_1 - y_2 - 3 \le 0
     \end{aligned}\\
      &&&\mathbf{x} \in [-10, 10]^2,\; \mathbf{y} \in [-10, 10]^2
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that I defined `\st` as a math operator. It's just to get spacing around it similar to `\max` and `\argmax`, otherwise the correct alignment would be trickier to produce. Another idea is to typeset the inner optimization problem using nested `aligned`, which is cleaner. But don't forget to brace the unary minuses, as `aligned` automatically thinks that an operator following `&` is binary.

[image: The result can be seen at the picture]