# Numbering All Equations in Two-Level Optimization Problem

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, alignment

Similar to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352538/aligning-two-level-optimization-problem), I need to construct a bilevel optimization.  The previous question received a [good answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352546/153291) except I need to number each equation even those in the nested `aligned` block.

What would be the simplest way to modify the structure below to support number of all equations? The nested `aligned` block yields a compile error if changed to `align`.

**MWE** (basic structure courtesy of @sergei-golovan)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\st}{s.t.}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \min \limits_{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}} \quad & {-}2x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 6y_1 + y_2^2 \\
    \st \quad & x_1^3 + 3x_2 - 10 \le 0 \\
        & \begin{aligned}
            \st \quad & {-}x_1 + 2x_1 - x_2^2 \le 0\\
                      & {-}x_1 + 2x_2 \le 0
          \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two possibilities with the `optidef` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{optidef}
\DeclareMathOperator{\st}{s.t.}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}|s|
 {\mathbf{x, y}}{-2x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 6y_1 + y_2^2}{\label{objective}}{}
\addConstraint{x_1^3 + 3x_2 - 10}{\le 0 \label{ineq:C1}}
\addConstraint{-x_1 + 2x_1 - x_2^2}{\le 0\label{ineq:C2}}
\addConstraint{-x_1 + 2x_2}{\le 0\label{ineq:C3}}
\end{mini!}

\begin{mini!}|s|[2]
 {\mathbf{x, y}}{-2x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 6y_1 + y_2^2\tag{2}}{\label{objective}}{}
\addConstraint{x_1^3 + 3x_2 - 10}{\le 0 \label{ineq:C1}}
\addConstraint{{-x_1} + 2x_1 - x_2^2}{\le 0\label{ineq:C2}}
\addConstraint{{-x_1} + 2x_2}{\le 0\label{ineq:C3}}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: a workaround for two-level constraints:

```
\begin{mini!}|s|[2]
 {\mathbf{x, y}}{-2x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 6y_1 + y_2^2\tag{2}}{\label{objective}}{}
\addConstraint{x_1^3 + 3x_2 - 10\tag{3}}{\le 0 \label{ineq:C1}}
\addConstraint{\st\quad}{{-x_1} + 2x_1 - x_2^2\le 0\label{ineq:C2}}
\addConstraint{\phantom{\st}\quad}{{-x_1} + 2x_2\le 0\label{ineq:C3}}
\end{mini!}
```

[image]

Comment: In these bilevel optimizations, the second set of constraints (e.g., Eq. (3) in the MWE needs a second `s.t.` since those constraints are specific to the first `s.t.` (Eq. (2)).  Is that possible in `optidef`?  My quick trial did not work.

Comment: I didn't have understood this. I'll try to find a workaround.

Comment: @ZaydH: I've added  another variant code. Does it correspond to what you want?

Comment: I am very sorry @Bernard for me being dense here but I do not see the edit above.  The "edited" link is not showing like it is for Isitar's answer.

Comment: @ZaydH: I'm afraid I posted it with another answer… :-( Anyway, now it's added to *this* answer.

Comment: Looks good thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use another package named optidef: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/optidef
here is your problem:

```
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{mini!}|s|[2]<b>
        {x,y}{-x^2_1+x^2_2-6y_1+y^2_2}
        {}{}
        \addConstraint{x^3+x_2-10}{\leq 0}{}
        \addConstraint{-x_1+2x_1-x^2_2}{}
        \addConstraint{-x_1+2x_2}{\leq 0}{}
    \end{mini!}
\end{document}
```

[image]